# Uberjar aborting because jar failed: duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Tags: java, jar, clojure, leiningen

I try `lein uberjar` on my project directory and I get this error

```
$ lein uberjar
Uberjar aborting because jar failed: duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

Could not find any specific solution online. How can I fix this?

---

**EDIT**

I found info about META-INF/MANIFEST.MF [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html) But why am I getting this error?

---

**EDIT 2**

I tried `lein uberjar` with another project and I got this:

```
$ lein uberjar
Warning: specified :main without including it in :aot. 
Implicit AOT of :main will be removed in Leiningen 3.0.0. 
If you only need AOT for your uberjar, consider adding :aot :all into your
:uberjar profile instead.
Created /Users/a/myapp/target/myapp-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Created /Users/a/myapp/target/myapp-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

So, is the problem with the application?

---

**EDIT 3**

This is my `project.clj`:

```
(defproject web_test "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [ring/ring-core "1.1.1"]]
  :ring {:handler web-test.core/handler})
```

---

**EDIT 4**

I created a new guestbook project following the instructions [here](http://www.luminusweb.net/docs#guestbook_application) but I still get an error about `manifest` issue. What am I doing wrong?

```
guestbook a$ lein uberjar
Created /Users/a/guestbook/target/guestbook-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Created /Users/a/guestbook/target/guestbook-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar

target a$ java -jar guestbook-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
no main manifest attribute, in guestbook-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar

target a$ java -jar guestbook.jar
no main manifest attribute, in guestbook.jar
```

**NOTE**

I figured out that I need to add `:main` to `project.clj` as explained [here](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/TUTORIAL.md)

Comment: You shoudn't. Every JAR has one and the `uberjar` should ignore them when building the composite JAR. Make a new project with the same dependencies, reproduce the problem, then start removing dependencies. Find which one causes the problem.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik ok, I'll try that later (I have to go to work now). But I pasted my `project.clj` above, there are only two dependencies. Do you want me to create a new project with the same two dependencies?

Comment: The point of making an empty project is removing any source code of your own and building only with the deps involved. Are you on Windows, by any chance?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, but EDIT 2 is for another project. The project that I am interested in, my original question, did not create the jar.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I am working on OS X

Comment: The project.clj you have posted doesn't work in my env (also OS X, btw). The error is with the backslash in `:url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html\
"}` How come this works for you?

Comment: And after I fix that (I have nothing besides your `project.clj`), it builds fine.

Comment: Sorry, emacs put a new line character there because the window was too small, I fixed it.

Comment: On my side: `$ lein version` ↵
`Leiningen 2.3.4 on Java 1.7.0_40 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM`

Comment: I have the same: `$ lein version Leiningen 2.3.4 on Java 1.7.0_45 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM`

Comment: I tried again with a new project but I still get a `manifest` error. I pasted it on the question, can you please take a look?

Comment: Search your project directory for `META-INF`. Example: `find . -name META-INF` and remove it. Lein should now build the uberjar.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I think it is editor-related (CounterClockWise?)

Indeed, after I cloned my git repo to another place in my file system, I could build without any problem.
However, after having imported the project into CounterClockWise as a Maven project, the issue reappeared.

(I know this belongs in a comment, not in a StackOverFlow answer, but I don't have the reputation for that yet. Hope someone will find out the reason for all this.)